# Adding rows to SQL query for each element in WHERE sequence

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have an SQL query like the following:

```
SELECT store_id, SUM(quantity_sold) AS count
FROM sales_table
WHERE store_id IN ('Store1', 'Store2', 'Store3')
GROUP BY store_id;
```

This returns a row for each store that has rows in `sales_table`, but does not return a row for those that do not. What I want is one row per store, with a `0` for `count` if it has no records.

How can I do this, assuming that I do not have access to a `stores` table?

Comment: No---or rather, it is in a different DBMS.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
with stores (store_id) as (
   values ('Store1'), ('Store2'), ('Store3')
)
select st.store_id, 
       sum(sal.quantity_sold) as cnt
from stores st
  left join sales_table sal on sal.store_id = st.store_id
group by st.store_id;
```

If you do have a `stores` table, then simply do an outer join to that one instead of "making one up" using the common table expression (`with ..`).

This can also be written without the CTE (common table expression):

```
select st.store_id, 
       sum(sal.quantity_sold) as cnt
from (
  values ('Store1'), ('Store2'), ('Store3')
) st
  left join sales_table sal on sal.store_id = st.store_id
group by st.store_id;
```

(But I find the CTE version easier to understand)

Comment: `values ('Store1', 'Store2', 'Store3')` will return a single row with three columns, not three rows with one column each.

Comment: +1. (BTW, even without an actual `stores` table, you can also define a subquery as `(SELECT 'Store1' AS store_id UNION SELECT 'Store2' UNION SELECT 'Store3') st`. Whether that's better/clearer than the `WITH` clause is a matter of opinion.) *Edit:* +1 retracted pending your fix for lanzz's comment.

Comment: @CharlesBretana: Yes. Or at least, it does in 8.4 and higher; I'm not sure about older versions.

Comment: @Charles [This answer on SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/489d1/2/0). You can see that it doesn't work with PostgreSQL 8.3

Comment: @CharlesBretana: ruakh is right. PostgreSQL has support for CTEs (including recursive ones) since version 8.4 .

Comment: @ruakh: no need for a `select ... union `. The `values` clause may be used anywhere where a table is allowed. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`unnest()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-array.html) to generate rows from array elements.

```
SELECT store, sum(sales_table.quantity_sold) AS count
FROM unnest(ARRAY['Store1', 'Store2', 'Store3']) AS store
LEFT JOIN sales_table ON (sales_table.store_id = store)
GROUP BY store;
```